# Problem with changing language using CultureInfo

Tags: c#

Language is not getting changed when we are giving specific culture like "fr-FR" through Resource File.please help me out of it if any one knows ,Thanks in advance.

```
  CultureInfo cinfo = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cinfo;
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cinfo;
```

The below code indicate that accessing the value through resource1 file according to the culture .

```
  _inboxpage.Text = Resource1.Ready;
```

Answer (score 1):

The resource files need to have a special naming convention to work transparently with different culture information.

You create a separate resource file for each language that you want to support or for a language and culture. Have one separate neutral resource file for the application to fall back upon in case the required key/value pair is not found.
ex:

Resources.resx  //neutral resource file

Resources.fr.resx //french specific file

**Resources.fr-FR.resx** //French language for France

and so on.

You can get more details here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I am using two resource file one is for english and another one is for french with the file name (1.CommonResource and 2.CommonResource.fr-FR) after changing the culture "fr-FR" i am not getting the data from the resource file (CommonResource.fr-FR) it just taking it from CommonResource File

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got a solution that while doing Localization in Plugin Application we need to copy that culture folders like "fr-FR" to corresponding Main Application then it will works fine.